# How to run a shiny app in IntelliJ (PyCharm)

Tags: r, intellij-idea, shiny, configuration

I have a basic shiny app (ui.r and server.r) that I am able to run in RStudio.

But seems like I can't run it in IntelliJ.
I have installed the R language support plug-in and I can run r scripts.

But when I try to run ui.r, the only thing I get is html output in the console.

Does anyone recognise this? I probably forgot to configure something?

I do have experience running java (web) apps with IntelliJ. With tomcat setup e.g.
In the run configurations, I didn't see anything specific for a shiny server or something R related. So I guess that is not where I should search ...

Any idea? Is more information needed?

Thx in adavance.

edit:
The answer is here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/R-895

Answer (score 1):

1. To run a shiny App (R framework) on PyCharm you must enable R first and indicate where is the R interpreter located:

[image]

2. R options appears on the bar status. One of them is R Console. Click on it. Write `getwd()` command to see if you are in the root directory of the project. If not, set it with `setwd()` command:

[image]

3. Next, write `runApp()` and **DO NOT** press `enter` yet. You must press `alt+enter` and  then click on load Shiny:

[image]

Comment: Running shiny apps with JetBrains IDEs is currently broken with R 4.3, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/R-1470